# Communication between sibling components

Tags: angular

I have thee following structure:

```
<master>
  <frame></frame>
  <toolbox></toolbox>
</master>
```

- master -> master component
- frame -> frame component (which loads an
  iframe)
- toolbox -> toolbox component

I add items from toolbox to the iframe with drang & drop and for each dropped element I add a click event via JS addEventListener. When I click an element I want to return some data and grab it into my toolbox component and display the clicked element.

I've tried using a service with EventEmitter (I know it's bad practice), but even if the data is received in the toolbox component, i can't do any changes to component variables.

By default propertiesPanel Input is set to "True", therefore my div is hidden.

```
<div class="selected-item" [class.is-hidden]="propertiesPanel"></div>
```

Then I have the component:

```
@Input() propertiesPanel = true;

ngOnInit() {
    // _connector is the Service I'm using for communication
    this._connector.get().subscribe(
         (data) => {
              this.propertiesPanel = false; // it changes the value to false
              this.addElements(); // dummy function - will have to add properties to the panel depending on which element I click
         }
    );
}
```

So, even if I set the Input to false, there's no action in the actual DOM whatsoever and I don't know why. (is-hidden class it's not removed)

Any thoughts?
Thanks

**Solution**

Apprently you need to use NgZone inside subscribe() in order to re-render the view... sort of.

```
this._ngZone.run(() => { 
    this.propertiesPanel = false; 
}
```

Comment: You confused with `propertiesButton` and `propertiesPanel `?

Comment: No, just copied it wrong.... sorry

Comment: Where are you getting the @Input data from(I mean parent component)?

Comment: The input is from toolbox component. I'm using it only there.

Comment: It looks fine for me. Can you reproduce the error using plunker

Comment: It's kindda tricky because of the iframe. But propertiesPanel changes to false, but nothing happens in the DOM - class is not removed. Maybe because I'm inside subscribe? Idk...

Comment: It must work. Once look at this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/QJLSXcpcELw3ZbMhlbyJ?p=preview

Comment: I know it works ok like that, but not inside a service subscription.

Comment: Yes, it does. `this` refers to current class even there also.

Comment: Apprently you need to use NgZone inside subscribe() in order to re-render the view... sort of.

`this._ngZone.run(() => {
this.propertiesPanel = false;
}`